# What is the default unit for width, height, padding etc in React Native for iOS?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am building a React Native application for iOS. The facebook documentation says width, height, padding, margin etc. takes a number.

I wanted to know what the default unit of styling is.

```
<View style={styles.box}>
   <Text style={styles.text}> Test Component </Text>
</View>

var styles = ReactNative.StyleSheet.create({
       box: {
          padding: 10,
          width:100,
          height:100,
       },
       text: {
          color: 'black',
          fontSize: 30,
       },
});
```

Comment: In ReactNative default unit is points or percentages as the screen size may vary based on different devices, this makes it easy to render the same component in different screen sizes.

Comment: When you need to define height/width based on device screen you can import Dimensions and use below  var width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
var height = Dimensions.get('window').height; use these variable directly in your StyleSheet, you can also add or subtract from them for generating different columns and layouts.

Answer (score 6):

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width):

> All dimensions in React Native are unitless, and represent density-independent pixels. Setting dimensions this way is common for components that should always render at exactly the same size, regardless of screen dimensions.

So the unit dimension is dp.

Answer (score 4):

## I Tested.

#### Android Native with DP unit

vs

#### Android React Native

[image: Android Native][image: Android React Native]

#### iOS Native with Point unit

vs

#### iOS React Native

[image: iOS Native] [image: iOS React Native]

## Result

**At least, the unit in RN is approximately the same as dp in Android and pt in iOS.**

Also, the unit in RN is applied sp value in Android for scale font size.

---

## Code

#### RN

```xml
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
        <View
          style={{
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            width: 150,
            height: 150,
            marginTop: 100,
            marginStart: 100,
          }}>
          <Text style={{color: 'black', textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 16}}>
            {'[React Native]\n100 x 100\nmargin top = 100\nmargin start = 100\n\nfontSize = 16\nㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁ'}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
```

#### Android

```xml
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="[ANDROID]\n\n100dp x 100dp\nmargin top = 100dp\nmargin start = 100dp\n\n textSize = 16sp\nㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁㅁ"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```