# Units for specifying width (of a table column) in Antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd

We are using the latest stable version 2 of [Antd](https://2x.ant.design/) (and cannot make the jump to version 3 due to version dependency constraints). How do we specify the width of my table columns, ideally to the length of the text in `title` property?  According to the [official `table` component docu](https://2x.ant.design/components/table/), there is the obvious property `width` for a `column`. All the documentation says in English is

> **Property:** width
>
> **Description:** Width of this column
>
> **Type:** `string|number`
>
> **Default:** -

1st part of the question: **If I specify only a number, what unit is used?** I tried different things, but it does not really look like it is `dp` as described e.g at [What is the default unit for width, height, padding etc in React Native for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42650857/what-is-the-default-unit-for-width-height-padding-etc-in-react-native-for-ios)

2nd part: **If I specify a string, which units can I use?** I tried `ex`, `em`, and `px` and none of them seems to work.

The 3rd part of the question: Maybe we overlooked **a property of the `table` tag which overwrites or limits the usage of `width` is a column?**

Any input is appreciated, already the translation of the original documentation to English would help. Or explaining the a related [Github issue: 'how to set table columns width? the width property is invalid'](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/14291).

Thanks for your time in advance - a puzzled Antd newbie.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the antd official document:

```
import { Table } from 'antd';

const columns = [{
  title: 'Name',
  dataIndex: 'name',
  key: 'name',
  width: '40%',
}, {
  title: 'Age',
  dataIndex: 'age',
  key: 'age',
  width: '30%',
}, {
  title: 'Address',
  dataIndex: 'address',
  key: 'address',
}];

const data = [{
  key: 1,
  name: 'John Brown sr.',
  age: 60,
  address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
  children: [{
    key: 11,
    name: 'John Brown',
    age: 42,
    address: 'New York No. 2 Lake Park',
  }, {
    key: 12,
    name: 'John Brown jr.',
    age: 30,
    address: 'New York No. 3 Lake Park',
    children: [{
      key: 121,
      name: 'Jimmy Brown',
      age: 16,
      address: 'New York No. 3 Lake Park',
    }],
  }, {
    key: 13,
    name: 'Jim Green sr.',
    age: 72,
    address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
    children: [{
      key: 131,
      name: 'Jim Green',
      age: 42,
      address: 'London No. 2 Lake Park',
      children: [{
        key: 1311,
        name: 'Jim Green jr.',
        age: 25,
        address: 'London No. 3 Lake Park',
      }, {
        key: 1312,
        name: 'Jimmy Green sr.',
        age: 18,
        address: 'London No. 4 Lake Park',
      }],
    }],
  }],
}, {
  key: 2,
  name: 'Joe Black',
  age: 32,
  address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
}];

// rowSelection objects indicates the need for row selection
const rowSelection = {
  onChange: (selectedRowKeys, selectedRows) => {
    console.log(`selectedRowKeys: ${selectedRowKeys}`, 'selectedRows: ', selectedRows);
  },
  onSelect: (record, selected, selectedRows) => {
    console.log(record, selected, selectedRows);
  },
  onSelectAll: (selected, selectedRows, changeRows) => {
    console.log(selected, selectedRows, changeRows);
  },
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Table columns={columns} rowSelection={rowSelection} dataSource={data} />
, mountNode);
```

Comment: I know that and I saw the percentage sign, but is that really the only possible way of specifying width? If I use percentages, I run into a [trouble with header formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58287043/) - a solution the client did not like too much.

Comment: No, you can set that to any valid width value... https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=001 this is the codepen from antd. Try changing the value width volumes. You can set it to 400, "400", "400px", "5em"... whatever.

Comment: That codepen link does not work... If in the official document where that code is present that i pasted... You can just click the codepen link in the upper right of that code snippet to open it up.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation - so it really looks like the width I am specifying is overwritten by something. If you could integrate your comments in your answer, I will accept the answer.